# How to configure STM32CubeIDE with Blackmagic Probe as a debugger?

Tags: stm32, debugging, stm32cubeide

I am trying to use my Blackmagic probe (an STM32 BluePill converted to a Blackmagic Probe) as a debugging device for the STM32CubeIDE and can't get to work!

I tried this solution: https://github.com/mike-pittelko/BlackMagic-STM32CubeIDE but with no luck,

I'm getting the following error:

> Error with command: usr/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb --version
> Cannot run program "usr/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb": Unknown reason

My Environment:

1- MacOs Catalina

2- STM32CubeIDE - Version: 1.5.1 - Build: 9029_20201210_1234 (UTC)

3- Debugging an STM32 Bluepill board with an STM32 Bluepill converted to a Blackmagic Probe!

Comment: That has nothing to do with blackmaguc, but rather is about gdb.  Did you install that version of gdb at the path mentioned in the error?  If not do so.  Or maybe the initial / is missing from the path.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, It is installed at the path, in fact, I have the latest version. I didn't quite understand what you meant by the initial being missing from the path?

Comment: See if you can execute the gdb by itself or if there is some issue which prevents it from running.  The given path would be incorrect unless the working directory were the root of the system as it is missing the leading / meaning that it is a relative rather than absolute path